# Rails5.2 accepts_nested_attributes_forの子モデルupdateに関して

Tags: ruby-on-rails

初めて質問させていただきます。
Rails5.2 を勉強中なのですが、 1 対多の複数モデルを update できずに困っています。

転職サイトのような構造を持つデータベースで、親が仕事内容 (job) 、子が募集職種で多の関係の (employment) であるモデルは以下のように記載しています。

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employment
end

class Employment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end
```

View を作り post されたデータを保存しようとすると、

```
Job.update(params[:job])
```

多の子モデル側を Select できないエラーが発生します。

```sh
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'employments.' in 'where clause': SELECT `employments`.* FROM `employments` WHERE `employments`.`job_id` = 1 AND `employments`.`` IN ('6', '9')
```

原因は上記の通り Where の `employments`.`` の部分の `` に id が入ってないからだと思いますが、この `` に id を指定する方法がわからず困っています。

何か子モデルのカラム指定する部分が不足しているでしょうか。

Comment: viewでどのようなformから`params[:job]`を受け取っているのか追記してもらってもよいですか

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。　申し訳ありません、自己解決しました。　原因はView側のform_withでjobのモデル指定をしていた部分をはずしたところ子モデルを含めて保存